single-valued continuous brach of argument
Let $D$ be a simple connected domain, $0 \notin  D$, prove that there exists a continuous funtion $\varphi \left( z\right)$ on $D$ such that $\varphi \left( z\right)  \in  \operatorname{Arg}z, \forall z \in  D$.
Geometrically it is OK, but how can we figure it out analytically?
Just use continuity, not a branch of $\ln z$?

What's a brach, some kind of candy?

the easiest to do it is to take $\phi(z)=\Im \log z$ where for $z \in D$ we define $\log z -\log z_0$ as the integral of $1/w$ on any (nice simple) curve starting from a fixed base point $z_0$ in $D$ and finishing at $z \in D$ and $\log z_0$ is a fixed value of the logarithm at $z_0$
